# Pasar a String un TextBox con formato C2 c#

Tags: c#

Tengo un tex box con formato C2 que contiene $5.000

pero  al momento de obtener el valor me obtiene lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
string st = txtSubTotal.ToString();
```

Es como obtengo el valor de ese TextBox. Como podria hacer para obtener solamente el valor numerico ???

Comment: has intentado con txtSubTotal.Text() ?

Comment: Si, pero me queda sacar el signo $

Comment: Pero te arroja junto con todo ese texto o solo con esto = `$5.000,00`?

Comment: Solo $5.000,00  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa la función `Replace`:

```
string st = txtSubTotal.Text().Replace("$","");
```

Comment: genial! Ahora tengo un problema con la "," , xq la tengo que sacar si o si, implemento nuevamente la funcion Replace(",",""); y en ves de tomarme 10.000 me toma 10

Comment: Osea, en el Text Box figura: 10.000,00   le tengo que sacar la coma para que en la base de datos se registre correctamente, pero al sacar la coma me registra un 10 en ves de un 10.000

Comment: Listo, ya lo arregle pasandolo a Double. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

También puedes utilizar `substring` en tu cadena para eliminar el primer caracter, el cual es el símbolo de moneda de la cadena de texto.

```
string st = txtSubTotal.ToString().Substring(1);
```

Y si necesitas hacer operaciones con la cifra, lo mejor es convertirla a tipo decimal.

```
decimal valor = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubTotal.Text.Substring(1));
```

Saludos.